# TextFormFields not changing while typing flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I have a flutter app.
Every TextFormField not changing while typing, but I can paste text there or set text using voice. Everything works instead of typing. There is no error in console while typing. And also, I have hint text on my keyboard, when I typed something, but it doesn't displays inside widget.

[image]

```
  TextEditingController _description = new TextEditingController();
```

```
                    TextFormField(
                      maxLines: 8,
                      controller: _description,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: AppLayout.getHeight(12),
                          horizontal: AppLayout.getWidth(16),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Styles.borderColor,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Styles.borderColor,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Styles.borderColor,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Styles.borderColor,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Агуулга',
                        hintStyle: Styles.textStyle1,
                      ),
                      onSaved: (val) => _description.text = val!,
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (val!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Та өргөдөл, гомдол үүсгэх агуулгаа оруулна уу!';
                        }
                        if (val!.length <= 5) {
                          return 'Та 5-с дээш үсэг оруулна уу';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    )
```

flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.8, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-MN)
• Flutter version 3.7.8 on channel stable at /Users/starig/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 90c64ed42b (2 days ago), 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500
• Engine revision 9aa7816315
• Dart version 2.19.5
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/starig/Library/Android/sdk
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
• VS Code at /Users/starig/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • E5C78BAD-ED19-49E4-B1AD-F4DC71A86F0A • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.110

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

Comment: You defined a focusedBorder, but I don't see your text field focused in the screenshot.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin It is focused. I just screenshooted it on blinked cursor

Comment: it seems that the issue is not in that part of your code, check this dartpad with your code https://dartpad.dev/?id=f860a8e432aeeae73588685916ea3545, it is working so the issue is not there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the cause of the issue you are describing, but this line of code is a problem:

```
if (val!.isEmpty)
```

If a value can be null, check if it's not null:

```
if (val == null || val.isEmpty)
```